# right click save as pdf is not coming in embed tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, birt

In my web page there is an Iframe and in this Iframe pdf is being generated by birt UI tool and working fine.
But Problem is when I right click on the pdf and do save as its saving it as a html not as pdf.

The structure of the dome element is like this

```
<iframe>
 #document
 <html>
  <embed ..... ></embed>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

Actually this link is being fired and which gives a form and after filling the form and submitting it the pdf file is coming

The link is `http://localhost:9090/ui_dashboard/frameset?__report=reports/RPT5008.rptdesign&__format=pdf&`

this gives a form and the then after submitting it pdf is generated runtime.

So in this embed the pdf is being generated and coming to browser.But when I right click it is considering it as a html element not as a pdf.

Please help

Comment: are you sure that the browser is attempting the save the PDF as HTML, or is it trying to save the actual parent HTML page?

Comment: Its saving a page called frameset.htm

Comment: http://localhost:9090/ui_dashboard/frameset?__report=reports/RPT5008.rptdesign&__format=pdf& 
this is the link and please see my edited question again.

Comment: A link to localhost? Seriously?

Comment: Once the PDF is opened in the site, you cannot click "Save As" on it, but there is a Save button in the PDF plugin. You need a link on the page, which returns only the PDF and that you can save with "Save As".

Comment: @BalintBako when a pdf is opened in the browser we can right click on the pdf and do save as right? and download as pdf..

Comment: No, you can't unless the PDF plugin has this feature. I just wrote how I see the problem. You need a link which points to the PDF and you can "RightClick & SaveAs" the link. Something like this: `<a href="/ui_dashboard/frameset?__report=reports/RPT5008.rptdesign&__format=pdf&">Save PDF</a>`, if that URL is returning the binary PDF